# The subgroups in this Hasse diagram represent which field extension?

Tags: group-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I can get the *Hasse diagram*(the subgroup lattice) easily by [*maple*](https://www.maplesoft.com/), such as for polynomial $x^3 - 2$:

```
DrawSubgroupLattice(GaloisGroup(x^3 - 2, x), 'indices')
```

[image]

According to the textbook, I know that the relationship between the extension of field and subgroups is like the graph below:

[image]

Here $r_1$,$r_2$ and $r_3$ are $\sqrt[3]{2}$,$\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}(-1+\sqrt{3} i)}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}(-1-\sqrt{3} i)}{2}$ respectively,which are the roots of $x^3 - 2$. But how about this *Hasse diagram* about polynomial $x^5+15x+44$(its *Galois Group* is `smallgroup(20,3)` or we call it `F(20)`):

[image]

What is the field extension represented by each of these subgroups? This information is not available from soft *maple*(I'm actually asking the same question [here](https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/235444-How-To-Draw-The-Relation-Of-The-Extension-Field)), so I'd like to ask for some advice here.

---

I can get The roots of the $x^5+15x+44$ by [this Wolfram Mathematica code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134551/21532), they are:
$\begin{cases}r_1=\frac{\sqrt[5]{2500 \sqrt{2}+2500}}{2^{2/5} 5^{4/5}}+\frac{-500 \sqrt{2}-500}{2^{4/5} \left(5 \left(2500 \sqrt{2}+2500\right)\right)^{3/5}}-\frac{2^{2/5} 5^{4/5}}{\sqrt[5]{2500 \sqrt{2}+2500}}-\frac{5\ 2^{4/5} 5^{3/5}}{\left(2500 \sqrt{2}+2500\right)^{2/5}}\\
r_2=-\frac{\sqrt[5]{-2500 \sqrt{2}-2500}}{2^{2/5} 5^{4/5}}+\frac{(-1)^{2/5} \left(-500 \sqrt{2}-500\right)}{2^{4/5} \left(5 \left(2500 \sqrt{2}+2500\right)\right)^{3/5}}-\frac{(-5)^{4/5} 2^{2/5}}{\sqrt[5]{2500 \sqrt{2}+2500}}+\frac{5 (-5)^{3/5} 2^{4/5}}{\left(2500 \sqrt{2}+2500\right)^{2/5}}\\
r_3=2^{2/5} 5^{4/5} \sqrt[5]{-\frac{1}{2500 \sqrt{2}+2500}}-5\ 2^{4/5} 5^{3/5} \left(-\frac{1}{2500 \sqrt{2}+2500}\right)^{2/5}+\frac{(-1)^{4/5} \sqrt[5]{2500 \sqrt{2}+2500}}{2^{2/5} 5^{4/5}}-\frac{\left(-500 \sqrt{2}-500\right) \left(-\frac{1}{5 \left(2500 \sqrt{2}+2500\right)}\right)^{3/5}}{2^{4/5}}\\
r_4=-\frac{(-1)^{3/5} \sqrt[5]{2500 \sqrt{2}+2500}}{2^{2/5} 5^{4/5}}-\frac{(-2)^{2/5} 5^{4/5}}{\sqrt[5]{2500 \sqrt{2}+2500}}-\frac{5 (-2)^{4/5} 5^{3/5}}{\left(2500 \sqrt{2}+2500\right)^{2/5}}-\frac{\sqrt[5]{-1} \left(-500 \sqrt{2}-500\right)}{2^{4/5} \left(5 \left(2500 \sqrt{2}+2500\right)\right)^{3/5}}\\
r_5=\frac{(-1)^{2/5} \sqrt[5]{2500 \sqrt{2}+2500}}{2^{2/5} 5^{4/5}}+\frac{(-1)^{4/5} \left(-500 \sqrt{2}-500\right)}{2^{4/5} \left(5 \left(2500 \sqrt{2}+2500\right)\right)^{3/5}}+\frac{(-1)^{3/5} 2^{2/5} 5^{4/5}}{\sqrt[5]{2500 \sqrt{2}+2500}}+\frac{5 \sqrt[5]{-1} 2^{4/5} 5^{3/5}}{\left(2500 \sqrt{2}+2500\right)^{2/5}}
\end{cases}$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141777/discussion-on-question-by-mayi-the-subgroups-in-this-hasse-diagram-represent-whi).